# ‘one more break’ error in sf plot. How to manipulate color palette for a continuous column in pal argument of sf plot function

Tags: r, colors, gis, r-sf, palette

I wonder why I the code below only works when I use 11 in the number of colors for `hcl.colors` function? Using other values caused an error `must have one more break than colour`.
If I’d like to represent the data in 4 class, for instance, what should I do? Would appreciate if someone could help me understand the reason.

```
dat1 <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", scale = 110)
plot(dat1["gdp_md_est"],
     key.pos = 4, 
     axes = FALSE,
     pal = hcl.colors(11, "Dark Mint", rev = TRUE),
     key.width = lcm(1.3), key.length = 0.75
)
```

using 11 colors produced the below map:
[image: r]

Comment: If you have 5 breaks at `c(0,5,10,15,20)` then you only need 4 colors to assign one each to 0-5, >5-10, >10-15, and >15-20 - that's `"one more break than colour"`

Comment: Hmm ... I didn't specify the number of breaks, right? only gave the 11 colors for palette. Is there any default setting on that for `sf` plot?

Comment: As you suggested, there is a default setting. `?plot.sf` informs that the style for the `breaks` argument defaults to "pretty" which is handed through to `classIntervals` (see `?plot.sf`) which then uses `pretty` to set the intervals. `pretty`, in turn, defaults to n = 5 intervals. Note that you can also have a peek behind the scenes by looking at the source of the class-specific plot method by entering `sf:::plot.sf` (mind the triple colon).

Comment: ^^^ accordingly, you can use the full range of your palette by setting `nbreaks = 12`.

Comment: That was a great guide @I_O. I've just checked the `classIntervals` function which mention this: _The "sd" style chooses breaks based on `pretty` of the centred and scaled variables, and may have a number of classes different from n; the returned par= includes the centre and scale values_.