# ‘Invalid color name error’ when using multiple color palette as a nested list in shiny selectInput for sf plot function

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf

Could someone help me understand what’s wrong with the below code. I would like to use two categories of color palette, single and multiple hue, for pal argument in the plot function of sf. Thanks in advance.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "pal", label = "Select a sequential color palette", 
                choices = list(
                  
                  `single hue` = list(
                    `Grays` = c("#F9F9F9", "#969696", "#1B1B1B"),
                    `Reds 3` = c("#F6F6F6", "#FF7078", "#69000C")),
                  
                  `multi hue` = list(
                    `Dark mint` = c("#D1FBD4", "#579C97", "#0E3F5C"),
                    `YlOrRd`  = c("#FFFFC8", "#F39300", "#7D0025"))
                )
    ),
    plotOutput("plot")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    dat1 <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", scale = 110)
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(dat1["gdp_md_est"],
           key.pos = 4, 
           axes = FALSE,
           pal = colorRampPalette(input$pal),
           key.width = lcm(1.3), key.length = 0.75
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a vector from `selectInput`. An option would be to return a comma-separated string and convert it into vector of colors.

Try the following -

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "pal", label = "Select a sequential color palette", 
                choices = list(
                  `single hue` = list(
                    `Grays` = "#F9F9F9,#969696,#1B1B1B",
                    `Reds 3` = "#F6F6F6,#FF7078,#69000C"),
                  
                  `multi hue` = list(
                    `Dark mint` = "#D1FBD4,#579C97,#0E3F5C",
                    `YlOrRd`  =   "#FFFFC8,#F39300,#7D0025")
                )
    ),
    plotOutput("plot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    dat1 <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", scale = 110)
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      col_vec <- unlist(strsplit(input$pal, ","))
      
      plot(dat1["gdp_md_est"],
           key.pos = 4, 
           axes = FALSE,
           pal = colorRampPalette(col_vec),
           key.width = lcm(1.3), key.length = 0.75
      )
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ronak. But I want to use colorRampPalette to interpolate between three colors specified in each nested list, so the output map should have multiple colors corresponding to `gdp_md_est` column value. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585977/one-more-break-error-in-sf-plot-how-to-manipulate-color-palette-for-a-continu) in my previous question.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Please see the updated answer. Is this what you were looking for? @rez